# How to Add Annotations to Parent Method in Java Without Overriding It?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

In Java, how can I add an annotation to a parent method without changing the body of the method.
For example:

```java
public class ParentClass {
  public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // Add the @Deprecated annotation to someMethod, without changing its body
}
```

I need the method to remain the same, but the only difference is now it has an annotation. How would I do this?

I have tried not including a body to the method, ie:

```java
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  @Override
  @Deprecated
  public void someMethod();
}
```

This doesn't work. I have also tried not using the `@Override` annotation, but it seems to expect that the method will have a body. Is there a way to just add the annotation without changing its actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do it like that:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void someMethod() {
        super.someMethod();
    }
}
```

However, here only calling `someMethod` on an object declared as `ChildClass` would be considered as call of a deprecated method. Calling `someMethod` on an object declared as `ParentClass` (even if it's actually an `ChildClass` object) wouldn't be seen as a deprecated method call.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  @Override
  @Deprecated
  public void someMethod(){
    super.someMethod();
  }
}
```